# Можно ли менять для LiveData observable, оставляя при этом observer неизменным?

Tags: android, viewmodel, room, livedata

Можно ли менять для `LiveData` observable, оставляя при этом observer неизменным?
В частности, у меня получается следующая ситуация. В Dao (Room) я возвращаю LiveData как результат метода:

```
@Dao
public interface DayDao {
  @Query("SELECT * FROM day WHERE date LIKE :date")
  LiveData<Day> getDay(String date);
}
```

ViewModel выглядит следующим образом:

```
public class DayViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {
    private AppDatabase appDatabase;
    private LiveData<Day> day;

    public DayViewModel(Application application) {
        super(application);
        appDatabase = App.getDatabase();
    }

    public LiveData<Day> getDay(String date) {
        Log.e(TAG, "getDay");

        day = appDatabase.dayDao().getDay(date);
        if (day != null && day.getValue() != null) {
            Log.e(TAG, "res = " + day.getValue().getDate());
        }
        return day;
    }
    ...
}
```

а получать данные из LiveData я хочу во фрагментe, у которого присутствуют следующие методы:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_day, container, false);
        ...

        model = ViewModelProviders.of(getActivity()).get(DayViewModel.class);
        String date = ...;
        dayLiveData = model.getDay(date);
        dayLiveData.observe(this, day -> {
            Log.e(TAG, "onObserve");
            // Update the UI.
        });
        return view;
}

public void updateTitle() {
        String date = ...;
        dayLiveData = model.getDay(date);
}
```

Метод `updateTitle()` вызывается из Activity. Однако по логам видно, что вызывается вначале - при вызове `onCreateView` метода - `onObserve` (и UI обновлятся), а после вызывается метод `getDay()` ViewModel-и, однако по логам видно, что

```
Log.e(TAG, "getDay");
```

отрабатывает, а

```
Log.e(TAG, "res = " + day.getValue().getDate());
```

нет, хотя данные для данного `date` точно должны быть (т.е. метод `appDatabase.dayDao().getDay(date)`, возвращающий просто `Day` точно вернул бы результат, а этот же метод, возвращающий `LiveData<Day>` - не возвращает). Можно ли всё же сделать такой обновление UI в методе фрагмента `updateTitle()` с помощью LiveData, или же это невозможно?

Comment: Log не срабатывает, т.к room возвращает пустую liveData, а значение передается только после обработки запроса в фоновом потоке. В методе updateTitle Вы просто присваиваете ссылке новое значение, на новую liveData нужно подписываться заного.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вам надо хранить и отображать date, а по нему вытаскивать и отображать данные из базы day, то вам поможет трансформация двух LiveData https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata#transform_livedata
Вы как раз сделали описанный там анти-паттерн - DO NOT DO THIS.

У вас должно быть примерно так - вместо addressInput -date, вместо postalCode - day.

```
class MyViewModel extends ViewModel {
    private final PostalCodeRepository repository;
    private final MutableLiveData<String> addressInput = new MutableLiveData();
    public final LiveData<String> postalCode =
            Transformations.switchMap(addressInput, (address) -> {
                return repository.getPostCode(address);
             });

  public MyViewModel(PostalCodeRepository repository) {
      this.repository = repository
  }

  private void setInput(String address) {
      addressInput.setValue(address);
  }
}
```

Comment: Да, я как раз переделала именно так, как Вы и описали, чуть раньше, чем увидела ответ, и это действительно работает) Спасибо! =)